# Retrieve the maximum IDENTITY id using transactionscope

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbcontext, transactionscope

Here is the code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    DBContext.AddtoSomeTable(record);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    DBContext.SaveChanges();

    MAX_ID = (from t in DBContext.SomeTable
              select t.ID).Max();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

As far as I know, before the scope is completed, the `MAX_ID` should be the new record's ID, which is just inserted. Even if there are two users submitting at the same time, the later one should wait until the first one's `TransactionScope` is completed.

But, what happens is the two users get the same `MAX_ID`. That means after the first person's record is inserted into the database, then the second one's record is inserted, and then the first person gets his `MAX_ID`.

I thought during a transaction the table was locked to avoid dirty data. Can anyone explain this?

Edit:
the ID field is auto incremented

Comment: I thought that the framework is suppose to return the id of the newly inserted object. Have you looked at what is returned in the record.yourid field?

Comment: @lrb the id is auto incremented, so the record didn't have that field, is that what you mean?

Comment: I am speculating that the Business Object that is inserted has an auto incremented primary key field, if properly configured the ID field of the BO will have a updated ID after the SaveChanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks of different types and scopes are taken during an operation and the lock scope will change due to lock escalation as the number of locks increases. If, in a single transaction, you are inserting/update/delete a single row in a single table, an exclusive row lock will most likely be taken. As you update/insert/delete more rows in that table, once you accumulate a certain number of row locks, *lock escalation* will promote them to page locks. Accumulate a sufficiency of page locks and you'll upgrade to a table lock.

I don't know what you're trying to do with `select max(id) from someTable`, but if you expect it to reflect what your `SaveChanges()` operation just did, most likely, you're creating a race condition.

Assuming you're using SQL Server, the built-in function **[`scope_identity()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)** will give you

> the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope.
>   A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch."

However: if, in the same scope, you, say, insert a row into two different tables, each having an identity column,

```
begin transaction
insert foo () ...
insert bar () ...
commit transaction
```

`scope_identity()` gives you just the last value that your scope generated (for the table `bar` in this example).

Comment: I am trying to get the record's auto incremented ID that I just inserted, and I am using the EF, which can't call the scope_identity() directly I think, but as @lrb mentioned, the solution is so simple actually, I can call MAX_ID = record.ID directly after SaveChange(). thanks all