# How to insert data to multiple tables in C#

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS( 
  ID INT NOT NULL, 
  NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
  AGE INT NOT NULL, 
  ADDRESS CHAR (25), 
  SALARY DECIMAL (18, 2), 
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS ( 
  ID INT NOT NULL, 
  DATE DATETIME, 
  CUSTOMER_ID INT references CUSTOMERS(ID), 
  AMOUNT VARCHAR (255), 
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I want to insert data into both table at a time, i.e. inserting the `ID` from table `CUSTOMERS` into `Customer_ID` in table `ORDERS`.

Please help me!

Comment: 1) You can create trigger against insertion of customer table. whenever the insertion happen in customer table then the trigger occure and it will pick last inserted record primary key(customer_ID) and make insertion in second table. 2) Make a store procedure that return customer_id after insertion of customer values and after that you can get customer_id and make another db call to insert enteries in orders table.

Comment: Can you tell us if you use ado.net, EF, LinqToSql etc

Comment: use max(customer_id)

Comment: @Sathish, that could run into problems if someone else is also inserting into the table at the same time, no?  Perhaps a transaction could help here?  I think scope_identity would be better for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve the maximum IDENTITY id using transactionscope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641787/retrieve-the-maximum-identity-id-using-transactionscope)

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
DECLARE @CustomerID INT

INSERT INTO Customer ...

SELECT @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM Customer
```

You'll get the last inserted customer ID and then insert to order table.